# python print command shows 'u prefix at the beginning of each string, why does this happen?

Tags: printing, prefix

I am new to Python and learning through codecademy. Throughout their exercises I've noticed that whenever I print a string or list of strings they get printed out with unicode prefixes. This is weird to me since I thought I would have had to specify strings as unicodes for python to spit them out with unicode prefixes. I read the following on the google python class webpage:

'Regular Python strings are *not* unicode, they are just plain bytes. To create a unicode string, use the 'u' prefix on the string literal'

Contrastingly, when I run the code I use for the codecademy exercise (namely the For your Hobbies exercise in section 2 of Loops) in terminal the strings get printed without the unicode prefixes...which is expected. What I did not expect is that terminal prints them without the prefixes even when I do specify my strings as unicode. I'm running python 2.7.2

Can you help me understand the specifics of string printing? Is this a platform specific issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[See this following stackoverflow question and the accepted answer on why you're getting the unicode markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855645/how-to-remove-the-u-as-in-unicode-in-usomestring).

The short version is you can wrap your return values in str() for plain, non-prefixed output.